# Is it possible to convert a raw gmail PDF attachment into a PDF file using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, email-attachments

Parsing a email in PHP using, file_get_contents('php://input');. The emails will all be from gmail and will all have one PDF attachment. The parsing turns the email attachment into an encoded format (base64 possibly). I would like to turn it back into a PDF file, but I'm not even sure which data is part of the PDF and which is just gmail formatting.

```
    X-Attachment-Id: f_jwqkv3w50

    JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjEwNDQgMCBvYaXplZCAxL0wgMTE1MTA5L08gMTA0
    OS9FIDM2OTA3L04gNC9UIDExNIDMxMF0+Pg1lbmRvYmoNICAgICAgICAgICAg
                         ... lots of data ...
    YmQ8uJSBifG/8ykGzdwxMDAyMmmCyjgEACm0LAwplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2Jq
    CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgoxMjYyMTMKJSVFT0YK
    --00000000000044d68b058afa7da0--
```

Is the --00000000000044d68b058afa7da0-- part of the PDF or a footer for header section? If it is possible to convert this data, any suggestions on the best way to go about it?

Comment: You have to identify exactly where the attachment data begins and where it ends. Everything in between should be the PDF contents.

Comment: I was able to extract it and used base64_decode to turn it back into a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse raw email content to extract a PDF fragment from the text.
Parsing part depends on email client wich sends email.
--00000000000044d68b058afa7da0-- - this is boundary string, it is not part of PDF.
Then clear PDF string You can save to file after base64 decode.
For gmail pdf attachement whole function can looks like this:

```
        $start = 'Content-Type: application/pdf';
        $pdfContent = mb_substr($messageRawContent, mb_strpos($messageRawContent, $start));
        //remove header lines
        $_pdfContent = mb_substr($pdfContent, strpos($pdfContent, "\n") + 1);
        $__pdfContent = mb_substr($_pdfContent, strpos($_pdfContent, "\n") + 1);
        $___pdfContent = mb_substr($__pdfContent, strpos($__pdfContent, "\n") + 1);
        $____pdfContent = mb_substr($___pdfContent, strpos($___pdfContent, "\n") + 1);
        $_____pdfContent = mb_substr($____pdfContent, strpos($____pdfContent, "\n") + 1);
        //remove boudary string
        $pdf = substr($_____pdfContent, 0, mb_strpos($_____pdfContent, "=="));
        $pdfDecoded = base64_decode($pdf);
        $pdfFilePath = 'path_to_file/file.pdf';
        file_put_contents($pdfFilePath, $pdfDecoded);
```